# How to return any value equal or similar MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to get a value typed into a search txtbox and the bank a similar or equal. Example.

Entered: G.

Returns: All names with G.

If the person typing go even write Giovanni. Only Giovanni will be returned.

My code but it just returns identical

```
[...]"select * from users where name = " + txt_name.Text, conn);
```

Comment: Your really should look into using parameters for you query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '" + txt_name.Text +"%'"
```

By the way use `Parameters` because your code is susceptible to **[Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** like: (I am using Sql here so just change it for mySql Connection, Adapter etc)

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
          string sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE @NameSearch";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameSearch", txt_Name.Text+"%");

                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(dt);                                                                   
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a wild character search like

If you want all the names anywhere having your text Use :

```
Select names from table where name like '%[your text]%'
```

If you want all the names starting with your text Use:

```
Select names from table where name like '[your text]%'
```

If you want all the names ending with your text Use :

```
Select names from table where name like '%[your text]%'
```

Comment: That would match any name that contains the text when the OP is indicating it should match anything that starts with the text.

Comment: put the wildcard only at the end ..where name like '[your text]%'

Answer (score 0):

Try [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator for that :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'G%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT names FROM table WHERE name LIKE '[your text]%'
```